# Build clang front end only for few languages ( say C and C++ )

Tags: clang, llvm

I am trying to build clang, however the build size is quite large. As clang supports non-C family languages as well ( e.g. Java, Fortran ), is there a way to turn that off during the build. I just want to have support for C and C++ and don't care about other languages.

Is there a CMake option that needs to be set to do that??

Thanks a lot!

Best Regards,
Nitish

Comment: Clang doesn't support Fortran or Java. Aren't you confusing it with gcc?

Answer (score 1):

As others have commented, clang is a C/C++ front end only, and there's no Java/Fortran front end to disable.

However, there are others ways to reduce clang build size:

- *Choosing a suitable build configuration*

  The default build configuration for LLVM/clang is `Debug`. Building for `Debug` (not specifying a build configuration) results with huge executables, and build folder may take > 20GB. This is primarily due to debug information.

  If you're not developing clang, and don't need debug information, you may build for `MinSizeRel`, which is a release build that is optimized for size.
- *Tweaking build settings*

  If you are planning to debug clang or do light clang developement, another option is building with a minimal debug information - the `-gmlt` option keeps line debug information only which allows source stepping, and results with much more compact object files, compared to full debug information (`-g`).
- *Disabling build components*

  You may disable some components from building, such as tests and examples:

  `-DLLVM_INCLUDE_TESTS=Off -DLLVM_INCLUDE_EXAMPLES=Off`

Putting it together:

`cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=MinSizeRel -DLLVM_INCLUDE_TESTS=Off -DLLVM_INCLUDE_EXAMPLES=Off`

For compact debug build:

`cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-gmlt -DLLVM_INCLUDE_TESTS=Off -DLLVM_INCLUDE_EXAMPLES=Off`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is easy: clang is C/C++ frontend, it does not support neither Java nor Fortran, therefore there is no such option - there is nothing to turn off.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how much it would help, but you could optimize your compilation of clang  for size. Disabling debug symbols as others have said should also help. Set `CFLAGS="-Os" CXXFLAGS="-Os"` as environment variables when you build clang.

This is from GCC 4.8.5

> -Os Optimize for size.  -Os enables all -O2 optimizations that do not typically increase code size.  It also performs further optimizations designed                                                                                                                                                                    to reduce code size.
>
> -Os disables the following optimization flags: -falign-functions  -falign-jumps  -falign-loops -falign-labels  -freorder-blocks
> -freorder-blocks-and-partition -fprefetch-loop-arrays  -ftree-vect-loop-version